# Why doesn't this regexp match?

Tags: python, regex

I am using python, and this regexp doesn't match, and I don't understand why.

```
string = "15++12"
if re.match("[-+*/][-+*/]+",string):
    # raise an error here
```

I am trying to raise an error, if one or more of "-","+","*","/" follows another one of those.

Comment: Python violates the Principle of Least Surprise here: they've chosen a word with an established meaning and warped it into meaning something different from that.  This isn't quite evil and wrong, but it is certainly stupid and wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) as [`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) only searches at the beginning of the string:

```
string = "15++12"
if re.search("[-+*/][-+*/]+",string):
    # raise an error here
```

Also, this could be simplified to:

```
string = "15++12"
if re.search("[-+*/]{2,}",string):
    # raise an error here
```

as the `{2,}` operator searches for two or more of the previous class.

Comment: I don't think he wants the second solution.  It looks to me like he wants to be able to search for ++, +++, ++++, +-+, etc.  [-+*/]{2} won't grab the entirety of any of the three character cases and will split the four character cases into two parts.

Comment: Your second solution is not what I want, but will accept your solution since you cleared search and match issue.

Comment: @Vorticity The `if` clause will be triggered in the same way as the first solution, but I'll change `{2}` to `{2,}` (which should then behave the same way as the first solution).

Answer (score 1):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) tries to match from the beginning of the string. To match any substring, either use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) or put a `.*` before the pattern:

```
>>> re.match("[-+*/][-+*/]+", s)
>>> re.search("[-+*/][-+*/]+", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f5639474780>
>>> re.match(".*[-+*/][-+*/]+", '15++12')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f5639404c60>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because re.match matches only the beginning of the string. Try re.search or re.findall

Check out 7.2.2 at python docs:
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

> Python violates the Principle of Least Surprise here: they've chosen a
>   word with an established meaning and warped it into meaning something
>   different from that. This isn't quite evil and wrong, but it is
>   certainly stupid and wrong. – tchrist @tchrist

I don't agree. In fact, I think exactly the contrary, it isn't stupid

If I say :

> a regex's pattern `"\d+[abc]"` matches the string **'145caba'**

everybody will agree with this assertion.

If I say :

> a regex's pattern `"\d+[abc]"` matches the string **'ref/ 789lomono
>   145abaca ubulutatouti'**

80 % of people will agree
and the other rigorous 20 % of people, in which I am, will be unsatisfied by the wording and will reclaim that the expression be changed to :

> `"\d+[abc]"` matches SOMEWHERE in the string **'ref/ 789lomono
>   145abaca ubulutatouti'**

That's why I find justified to call an action that consists to search if and where a pattern matches in a string: `search()`

and to call the action to verify if a match occurs from the beginning: `match()`

For me it's very much logical, not surprising

.

PS

A former answer of mine have been deleted. As I don't know how to write to the author of the deletion to ask him the reason why he judged my former answer being a rant (!!!?), I re-post what seems to me absolutely impossible to be qualified so

Comment: Ask yourself this: is what you have written here *an answer to yasar11732's question?* If not, it should not be posted *as an answer*. You have enough rep to comment on the question; use `@tchrist` in a comment to have tchrist notified of your comment.